# Error Upgrading Fabric component [orderer.common.server] Main -> ERRO 001

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm practicing upgrading network components (orderer and peers) following the official hyperledger fabric docs. In particular I'm following this [link](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/upgrading_your_components.html) to upgrade the orderer. I'm able to follow all steps, but I get an error at the last step when bringing up the orderer:

```bash
/test-network docker logs b0d56da4a9f082bc7c5c0dea1e81ba3bf30c55be8f306b0a27986c706a056da4
2022-10-24 14:53:07.899 UTC [orderer.common.server] Main -> ERRO 001 failed to parse config:  Error unmarshaling config into struct: 2 error(s) decoding:

* cannot parse 'General.ListenPort' as uint: strconv.ParseUint: parsing "'7050'": invalid syntax
* cannot parse 'General.TLS.Enabled' as bool: strconv.ParseBool: parsing "'true'": invalid syntax
```

These are the commands I'm executing in order:

```bash
#1. Stop the ordering node.
docker stop $ORDERER_CONTAINER

#2. Back up the ordering node’s ledger and MSP.
docker cp $ORDERER_CONTAINER:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/ ./backup/orderer/$ORDERER_CONTAINER
docker cp $ORDERER_CONTAINER:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/ ./backup/msp/$ORDERER_CONTAINER

#3. Remove the ordering node container.
docker rm -f $ORDERER_CONTAINER

#4. Launch a new ordering node container using the relevant image tag.
docker run -d -v ${PWD}/backup/orderer/$ORDERER_CONTAINER/:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/ \
            -v ${PWD}/backup/msp/$ORDERER_CONTAINER/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/ \
            --env-file ./envord.list \
            --name $ORDERER_CONTAINER \
            hyperledger/fabric-orderer:$IMAGE_TAG orderer
```

After I execute the last command I get:

```bash
b0d56da4a9f082bc7c5c0dea1e81ba3bf30c55be8f306b0a27986c706a056da4
```

The container is created but fails to start with the error presented above. Any clues?

Comment: which variables do you have in ./envord.list

Comment: For the orderer, I had exported all **ORDERER_GENERAL_** variables from the container before bring it down.  `set | grep -i orderer_general > envlist.list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. When I exported the variables from the orderer container before bring it down for the update, for some reason they where saved as follow:

```bash
ORDERER_GENERAL_EXAMPLE='example value'
```

The values for all variables were enclosed between single quotes. I removed those single quotes and the problem was solved.